# Test the function "System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, razor, rhino-mocks

I want to (unit)test the function `System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView` and check the correct return of the HTML Code.

But every time I start the unit test, it throws an `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` exception.

I've tried to debug through the .net framework source but the debugger gets disoriented and jumps randomly / breaks with no message.

Now I want to know what element I’ve missed in the `FakeControllerContext` and how to fix it.

Here's my Code:

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model, ControllerContext controller)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = controller.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    controller.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        //"Error: ***.Shop.UnitTests.RenderStuffTest.RenderPartialViewToStringTest-Test method threw an exception: System.NullReferenceException – Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller, viewName);
        controller.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        controller.Controller.ViewBag.Part = true;

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller, viewResult.View, controller.Controller.ViewData,
                                      controller.Controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

And here's my test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void RenderPartialViewToStringTest()
    {
            const string viewName = "_navi";
            var customersController = new ArticleController();
            customersController.ControllerContext = new FakeControllerContext(customersController)                                      {                                                           RouteData =
                                                        {
                                                            Route =
                                                                new Route(
                                                                "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                                                                new MvcRouteHandler())
                                                            ,
                                                            RouteHandler = new MvcRouteHandler()
                                                        },
                                                };

            customersController.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Add("language", "German");
            customersController.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", "Article");
            customersController.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
            customersController.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Add("id", "");
            var model = (...);
            string actual = RenderStuff.RenderPartialViewToString(viewName, model, customersController.ControllerContext);
            (...)
        }
```

For the mocking I’ve used `Rhino.Mocks` and the `MvcFakes` from [Stephenwalther.com](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/01/asp-net-mvc-tip-12-faking-the-controller-context.aspx)

Comment: Maybe it's trying to read `HttpContext.Current` from the thread which won't be set. Why do you want to unit test this? Try downloading the MVC source - you should find Microsoft's existing unit test in there.

Comment: I've got a got a view for an article.
This View is used for the website and for emails with article recommendation.
But there is little difference in the html between these two calls.

Now I want to write a test that checks the view for these two calls.

Maybe I didn’t found the right unit test in the mvc project files but I don’t get a test that actually renders the html

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8861211/660898) can help you, you have to mock the `ViewEngine` then mock the `FindPartialView` call.

Comment: IIRC it's the FindPartialView call he's intested in - he wants to mock up enough of the surrounding classes so that he can run the real FindPartialView code, not mock it.